# Stripping first 5 characters of a string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following Code;

```
For Each test In gvForecasts.Columns
            Dim test2 = test.caption
            test2 = test2.Substring(0, 5)
        Next
```

test2 will return a value of "Week 1"

I want to be able to strip this string so that it only returns "1"

However the following error message gets returned; "Index and length must refer to a location within the string."

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4):

Substring method's first parameter is the index from where you want to start and next parameter is number of characters that you want to grab.

try this code:

```
If test2.Length > 5 Then
            test2 = test2.Substring(5, 1)
Else
            Throw New Exception("Invalid source string")
End If
```

& if you want to eliminate just first 5 characters, you can use following code:

```
If test2.Length > 5 Then
            test2 = test2.Substring(5)
Else
            Throw New Exception("Invalid source string")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

[Your usage of vb.net's `subString()` method is incorrect.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Specifically, your method is grabbing the first 5 characters of the string (`Week_`).

It should be used as `subString(5)` to return all characters from the 5th one onwards.

Comment: I liked Sankalp's checking of the input data to be sure that we do indeed have 5 characters, but then he only takes one of them. Your solution gets the right answer, but would benefit from input checking...

Comment: Most things do benefit from input checking - however, checking for input validity wasn't included as part of the question.

Comment: @Psychemaster - Doesn't matter if it's specified in the question or not. If you're going to take everything after the 5th character, then there had better be 5 characters or more in your original string, or the job becomes invalid...

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the last number of a string where each token is separated by a space?

You could use `String.Split` and this query:

```
For Each test In gvForecasts.Columns
    Dim words = test.caption.Split() ' splits by all white-space characters
    Dim num As Int32
    Dim numberParts = From word in words Where Int32.TryParse(word, num)
    Dim weekNumber As String = numberParts.LastOrDefault()
Next
```

Side-Note: as mentioned already by Psychemaster you need to use the overload of `String.Substring` with a single parameter to omit `n`-characters and take the rest.

```
test2 = test2.Substring(5) ' will throw an exception if the string is not long enough
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Substring and specify a length that is longer than the string it will throw an exception. It will also throw an exception if you have a blank string.

However from your description I think what you actually want is the last character. So you just need to do some extra checking:

```
    'check the string has something in it and is the correct length
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) AndAlso s.Length >= 1 Then
        test2 = ""
    Else
        'get the last character of the string
        test2 = s.Substring(s.Length - 1)
    End If
```